# Camel Spring boot application.properties doesn't support dynamic values

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm using camel in spring boot. I want to save file in dynamic name. Example using current timestamp for file name like `"Prefix-20170612115230.xml"`. I can do that if I hard code it like `from(FTP).marshal().to("file:tmp/outbound?fileName=Prefix-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.xml")`.

But if I add this value to `application.properties` as `outbound.ftp.location=file:tmp/outbound?fileName=CA-RP-na-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.xml` and using this value in route as `from(FTP).marshal().to("{{outbound.ftp.location}}")`, then the file name is something like `Prefix-now:yyyyMMddHHmmss.xml`.

What is the right way to use application.properties for this. I guess I need to escape `$` sign but escaping it like `#{'$'}` didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$simple{date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}`, see the *alternative syntax* information bot at: http://camel.apache.org/simple.html